# RabbitMQ is not getting auto-configured in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

When I looked at the Spring Boot official documentation, it says that Spring Boot will auto-configure the RabbitMQ and generate a bean for `RabbitTemplate`, however, when I used `@Autowired` to inject it, the application failed to start and gave me this error message:

```
Field rabbitTemplate in xxx.xxx.queue.publisher.XXXPublisher required a bean of type 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

Does anyone know why it does not auto-configure it?  I will be grateful for any answer!

PS: I have `@SpringBootApplication` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotated in my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableRetry
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class XXXApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(XXXApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share the pom.xml file and rabbitmq service file for more update

Comment: @FazlanAhamed Well, it turns out it is because I explicitly exclude the RabbitAutoConfiguration in the application.properties file somehow previously...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out it is because I explicitly exclude the `RabbitAutoConfiguration` in the `application.properties` file somehow previously...